# Is it possible to apply graduate program in a different major?

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, business-school

I'm a business student and I'm really fond of computer science and engineering. Is it possible to apply for cs major in computer science? If not, is it possible to apply for MaSc in Master of Business Analytic then continue to study in CS?

Comment: Would depend entirely on the school.  You should ask the registrar's office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific degree doesn't matter as much as your other experience. If you are a business student, but have focused on coursework in CS/engineering, done undergraduate research in a CS/engineering lab, etc, you have a better shot.

I am assuming you are roughly a senior undergraduate student based on your question, but I would also advise that if you are truly finding yourself more interested in CS/engineering it might be to your benefit to take an additional undergraduate year and get some of the required courses under your belt for the graduate programs you will be interested the following year. Graduate program staff at your current institution are probably a good resource for what types of courses would benefit you.

Answer (score 0):

As a "business" student, you should focus your major as much as possible on information technology or computer systems to the extent possible. Most business applications have leanings in that direction, so I would try to take business courses with those kinds of leanings. Perhaps only "marketing" courses have few connections with computer science. Here, I'm not referring to subjects like market research (which have plenty of computer applications), but more to the "behavioral" or sociological efforts of marketing such as selling.

The other way of strengthening your candidacy is to take your non-business electives in computer science and engineering. To get into a graduate program in these areas, you don't need to be the "best candidate" (e.g. an electrical engineering major from Stanford or MIT), only a "plausible candidate.